# .getFeatures() method for ol.source.Vector instance working in console, but not in script

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm trying to return the attributes of a vector source in OpenLayers (v.4) using the .getFeatures function some indexing, and the .get('key') method, like so: `gdeltVectorSource.getFeatures()[15].get('count')`.  When I enter this into the developer console in Chrome, the result is as expected and it works just fine.  However, when added to the script referenced in the html document, it returns: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined at pen.js:46`.  It seems to fail to return an array of features from .getFeatures().  Can someone help me understand why this occurs?  I'd like to return attributes of a vector source in order to use the values ('count' in this example) in styling, etc.  Is there something about how javascript compiles and runs code that I'm missing?

Here's [a link to a codepen](https://codepen.io/toddjacobus/pen/MXVeVy?editors=1111) that illustrates what I'm talking about. The points don't display (I don't know why, but it's irrelevant), but the source loads just fine.  Also note, you'll have to open the chrome console to see error message.

Thank you for stopping to read my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$.ajax` call is asynchronous.  You need to process/use the features in the callback function when/where they exist:

current code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: gdeltURL,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        // console.log(typeof JSON.stringify(data))
        // 'canot read property 'readFeatures' of undefined
        var geojsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
        // console.log(typeof geojsonFormat)
        var features = geojsonFormat.readFeatures(data, {
        });
        gdeltVectorSource.addFeatures(features);
    }
});

// snip...
console.log(gdeltVectorSource.getFeatures()[15].get('count'))
```

should be:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: gdeltURL,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        // console.log(typeof JSON.stringify(data))
        // 'canot read property 'readFeatures' of undefined
        var geojsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
        // console.log(typeof geojsonFormat)
        var features = geojsonFormat.readFeatures(data, {
        });
        gdeltVectorSource.addFeatures(features);
        console.log(gdeltVectorSource.getFeatures()[15].get('count'))
    }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/nxcb0t9g/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var osm = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

function styleFn(f) {
  var retSytle;
  f.set('styledwithcolor', "red");
  retSytle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 6,
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'white',
        width: 2
      }),
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: "red"
      })
    })
  });
  return [retSytle];
}

var gdeltVectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  // format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
})

var gdeltLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: gdeltVectorSource,
  visible: true,
  style: styleFn
});

var gdeltURL = "https://api.gdeltproject.org/api/v2/geo/geo?query=theme:WB_1791_AIR_POLLUTION&format=GeoJSON"

$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: gdeltURL,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    // console.log(typeof JSON.stringify(data))
    // 'canot read property 'readFeatures' of undefined
    var geojsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
    // console.log(typeof geojsonFormat)
    var features = geojsonFormat.readFeatures(data, {
      featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
    });
    gdeltVectorSource.addFeatures(features);
    console.log(gdeltVectorSource.getFeatures()[15].get('count'))
  }
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [osm, gdeltLayer],
  target: 'map',
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
    attributionOptions: {
      collapsible: false
    }
  }),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-11000000, 4600000],
    zoom: 4
  })
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.6.5/ol-debug.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The features are loaded in the ajax call, which returns after the remaining code (creating the map and trying to display the count value) has executed.

Getting the desired feature attribute works fine. You can try putting the call within the ajax function.

To solve your issue, either don't use ajax or ensure the features are loaded before accessing them.